# Scrolling snap to horizontal and vertical grid - Jerky scollLeft

Tags: jquery, grid, scrolltop

I am aiming to create a grid that always snaps to the top and left edge of the browser when a user scrolls vertically or horizontally. I have the basic version working but the `scollLeft` part is always really jerky compared to the `scrollTop` animation.

If anyone think of a better solution, I would be very grateful, it is slowly driving me insane!

Here is the bones of it so far http://jsfiddle.net/stuart09876/vXvBV/1/

And here is the script...

```
$(function(){
    var windowtest = $(window);
    var _top = $(windowtest).scrollTop();
    var _left = $(windowtest).scrollLeft();
    var individualDivHeight = 140;
    var individualDivWidth = 220;

    $(windowtest).scroll(function(){
        var _cur_top = $(windowtest).scrollTop();
        var _cur_left = $(windowtest).scrollLeft();
        var totalHeight = $('#container').height();
        var totalWidth = $('#container').width();
        var posToScroll = Math.round(_cur_top / individualDivHeight) * individualDivHeight;
        var posToScrollLeft = Math.round(_cur_left / individualDivWidth) * individualDivWidth;

        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: posToScroll}, 100,
            function(){
                $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollLeft: posToScrollLeft}, 100);    
            }
        );              
    });
});
```

Many Thanks

Stuart